# I am unable to run my Laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-artisan, artisan-serve

good afternoon. I'm encountering some issues running a Laravel application locally. I don't have much knowledge about Laravel or PHP Artisan, and I could use a little help. I'm not familiar with the specifics of this problem, but I suspect it might be related to the database since it seems to be attempting a connection.

> ERROR: Illuminate\Database\QueryException could not find driver (SQL:
> select * from banners where status = 1 order by order asc)

I've already tried changing the `.env` to `APP_DEBUG=false APP_ENV=local`, but without success. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think, you have not php-mysql extension installed on system (or pgsql, depends on your database)

Comment: Is this local? production? How are you serving your app. Xampp? Wampp? docker? Like what @Maksim said, you might have a missing extension. If you are using xampp or wampp locally, such extensions are installed by default.

Answer (score 1):

1. You may configure the .env file in the root directory, you should configure it like I did

`DB_CONNECTION=mysql`
`DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`
`DB_PORT=3306`
`DB_DATABASE=laravel`
`DB_USERNAME=laravel`
`DB_PASSWORD=laravel`

2. pdo_mysql extension is not enabled

`Linux: Add this line extension=pdo_mysql.so to the php.ini file`
`Windows: Add this line extension=pdo_mysql.dll to the php.ini file`